# Military Amateur Radio Service (MARS)

Tags: emergency

The Navy MARS program was officially decommissioned effective 30 September 2015. What is the state of the other MARS programs (Army and Air Force)? Is it known that they too will be decommissioned in the next few years?

Comment: I've edited your question so that it isn't quite so much asking for _speculation_ on the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Army and Air Force MARS are very much alive and well, and growing.  There is no reason to believe that either will be decommissioned as the volunteer base continues to grow as well as the customer base.